# Is it possible to get the pre previous website from which user came

Tags: search, google-analytics, referrer

Is it possible by using Google analytic cookie or JavaScript referrer get from which pre previous page user came.

I mean for example I have marketing website:

```
test.com
```

And application:

```
app.test.com
```

Cookies/ Referrer I need to get from app.test.com. Is it possible to do it. Or only 1 was to get it is on test.com ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking which referrer app.test.com will receive, or are you trying to see if they've visited test.com before?

Comment: No, I want to get the url from which user come for example dummydomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tracking is set up properly and with the same Google Account you can (at least in the e-commerce reports and in custom reports) set the secondary dimension to "full referrer" or "referral path".

If your visitors comes from dummydomain.com, visits test.com and then goes to app.test.com the reports for app.test.com will show dummydomain.com as referer.